# Time in Known Location with Known Offset and NO Daylight Saving Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

With the hundreds of posts concerning Javascript time questions, I'm certain this has been addressed but I've been through a couple of dozen posts so far and none answer my specific question. I know the offset (-7) and in this particular State in the USA (Arizona) there is NO DST. I just want to display the time in Arizona to any user. All the posts I've reviewed seem to imply that I need to use

```
return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

from the local computer as part of my calculations but I'm not sure why that would be necessary? Would this be a viable solution?

```
const now = new Date();
        return {
            hour: (now.getUTCHours() -7)
            minute: now.getMinutes(),
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to `getTimezoneOffset`, but you will need to handle the case when the hours are smaller than 7:

```js
const now = new Date();
        console.log( {
            hour: ((now.getUTCHours() -7) % 24),
            minute: now.getMinutes(),
        });
```

Comment: I see the problem you are pointing out. But I thought I needed "getUTCHours" to then "subtract 7"? Doesn't getHours() method return the hour for the specified date, according to local time?

Comment: @ND_Coder you were thinking correctly and I edited my answer since you have read it, doing radical changes :) But, the `%24` is still needed.

Comment: Oops. I think I missed your edit. I see now what you are doing. Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: And for a 12-Hour clock, I think this will then work? hour: ((now.getUTCHours() -7) % 12 || 12)

Comment: @ND_Coder if the period is 12 rather than 24, then this is correct. But I do not understand why you need to handle this. Do you have an AM/PM format?

Comment: That was my hope. Just a nice touch for those who follow am/pm. Everything working so far so, again, thank you!

Comment: You should use `getUTCMinutes` as well.  (There are time zones that are 30-minute or 45-minute offset from UTC.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no DST in Arizona *presently*, but that doesn't mean there never will be.  Sure, unlikely - but not impossible.

A more robust solution, which also accounts for locale formatting preferences of the user, is as follows:

```js
const s = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {
  timeZone: 'America/Phoenix'
});
console.log(s);
```

This will work with any [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), accounting for DST when applicable, or not - depending on the time zone.

If you want the exact output as in your question, try something like this:

```js
const s = new Date().toLocaleString('en', {
  timeZone: 'America/Phoenix',
  hour12: false,
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric'
});
const p = s.split(':');
const o = {
  hour: parseInt(p[0]),
  minute: parseInt(p[1])
};
console.log(o);
```

Comment: Not only DST, but historic offset changes as well should the OP, for example, decide to generate dates and times in the 1800s. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Intl* object and Etc pseudo–timezone for a fixed offset. The EMCAScript version only supports whole hour offsets and the sign is the reverse of convention.

E.g.

```js
console.log('Current time in UTC-7: ' +
  new Date().toLocaleString('default',{timeZone:'Etc/GMT+7', hour:'numeric', minute:'2-digit'})
);

console.log('Current time in UTC-7: ' +
  new Date().toLocaleTimeString('default',{timeZone:'Etc/GMT+7'})
);
```